# Uploading svg images to SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I make a request to the server and in response I get an svg image. I tried to display it using AsyncImage(), but it didn't work. Is there any solution to this problem?

So I tried to do:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://s3-symbol-logo.tradingview.com/applovin--big.svg"))
```

But this led to the fact that just placeholder was shown:
[image: But this led to the fact that just placeholder was shown]

Comment: Please include some reproducible sample/code/image, otherwise there is no way we could answer to your question.

Comment: @tail I have added additional information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two ways to implement SVG images in your project one is via using a library on GitHub called [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) (this way is expensive using the ram and slows down the loading time a little), but the other way that was perfect is using:

two libraries:
1- [SDWebImageSVGCoder](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSVGCoder)
2- [SDWebImageSwiftUI](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImageSwiftUI)

after you add these libraries to your project through the Xcode package dependencies, you write this code to set it up and use it.

```
import SwiftUI
import SDWebImageSVGCoder

@main
struct Package_trialsApp: App {


        init() {
            setUpDependencies() // Initialize SVGCoder
        }
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView()
            }
        }
}

// Initialize SVGCoder
private extension Package_trialsApp {
    
    func setUpDependencies() {
        SDImageCodersManager.shared.addCoder(SDImageSVGCoder.shared)
    }
}
```

after setting that up you can use it like this:

```
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

WebImage(url: "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/423378/car-service.svg", options: [], context: [.imageThumbnailPixelSize : CGSize.zero])
                                .placeholder {ProgressView()}
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
```

Bonus:
you can also do something like this to make your code more efficient and more reusable:

```
import SwiftUI

import SDWebImageSwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let imageArray = [
        URL(string: "https://www.svgrepo.com/show/423378/car-service.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svgfiles/androi.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg"),
        URL(string: "https://jpeg.org/images/jpeg-home.jpg")
    ]
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            
            Link(destination: URL(string: "https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/android.svg")!, label: {
                Text("Sample SVG image")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
            })
            
            ForEach(imageArray, id: \.self) { url in
                if let bolean = url?.absoluteString.suffix(3).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains("svg") {
                    if bolean {
                        HStack {
                            WebImage(url: url, options: [], context: [.imageThumbnailPixelSize : CGSize.zero])
                                .placeholder {ProgressView()}
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                        }
                    } else {
                        AsyncImage(url: url, content: { phase in
                            switch phase {
                            case .empty:
                                ProgressView()
                            case .failure:
                                Color.red
                            case .success(let image):
                                image.resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                                
                                
                            @unknown default:
                                fatalError()
                            }
                            
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I found a solution and posted another answer, please check it out in this forum

There is no solution for this, because .SVG images are not actually images,
they are actually files (SVG: Scalable Vector Graphics) and they are based on calculations and not actual pixels.

The best option for you is to tell your backend to convert all .SVG files into .PNG or .JPG files and then give you the images urls in that format.

Or another valid option is to download the image into your project assets and then give it the name of the URL and whenever you are provided with the url you just use it like this:

```
Image("https://s3-symbol-logo.tradingview.com/applovin--big.svg")
```

I have been trying to do the same thing as you are but I only found one solution: present the .SVG image in a webView. if you are intrested you can find it here ([Presenting .SVG as a web View](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/how-do-i-display-an-svg-image-from-a-url-in-swiftui/9248)) but keep in mind it is not optimal

Answer (score -4):

Looks like it's your image link problem.

I tested two `AsyncImage`, my link worked, but your link did not.

Try checking whether your link is the right path for the image loading.

Code is below the image:[image]

```
 VStack {
        //my link worked
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://picsum.photos/200")) { image in
            image.resizable()
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        
        //your link did not work. result in loading.
        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://s3-symbol-logo.tradingview.com/applovin--big.svg")) { image in
            image.resizable()
        } placeholder: {
            ProgressView()
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
```

Comment: My link is correct. Try to copy "https://s3-symbol-logo.tradingview.com/applovin--big.svg " and paste it into google, the image will load there

Comment: The one that works for you is a JPG image, not an SVG, so you're not proving anything about SVGs loading with your technique with it